# What's the meaning of "faults" in Android ANR log?

Tags: android, logcat

As in the following example, besides the cpu usage value in each process, there's also a pair of **"faults"** values in "minor" and "major". What's the exact meaning?

```
ANR in com.rescuetime.android
PID: 11517
Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50000010 }
Load: 3.35 / 5.22 / 9.91
CPU usage from 0ms to 7475ms later with 99% awake:
  97% 947/system_server: 80% user + 16% kernel / faults: 7489 minor 81 major
  0.1% 269/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4711 minor 16 major
  7% 1493/com.android.phone: 3.3% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 3615 minor 10 major
  6.5% 1201/com.android.systemui: 3.3% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 3074 minor 5 major
```

Comment: ANR (Application Not R esponding ) is due to handling long running task in Main Thread (UI thread). If the main thread is stopped for more than 5 sec.

Comment: I understand the meaning of ANR, but seeking an explanation of the "faults" value shown in ANR log.

Comment: My guess is that it's counting page faults with the memory system. But I wish there were more documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the minor/major fault is just the minor/major page fault in Linux Kernel terminology. Explanation for them can be found on the Internet.

Android is reading such data from the proc file system. For a particular pid, the data is read from "/proc/" + pid + "/stats". One example of that is copied below:
/proc/24759 # cat stat
24759 (t_app_installer) S 2580 2580 0 0 -1 1077952832 13620 0 177 0 40 25 0 0 20 0 15 0 44123212 1066246144 12491 4294967295 2248540160 2248562159 3202042320 3202035120 2966304256 0 4612 1 1073775864 4294967295 0 0 17 6 0 0 0 0 0 2248567976 2248568832 2249576448 3202042577 3202042653 3202042653 3202043876 0

As of now, the 10th value is the minor fault. 13620 in this case. And the 12th is the major fault.